# Eliminate duplicate columns based on separate field using awk array?

Tags: arrays, awk

I am trying to eliminate a set of duplicate rows based on a separate field.

`cat file.txt`

```
1    345   a    blue
1    345   b    blue
3    452   c    blue
3    342   d    green
3    342   e    green 
1    345   f    green
```

I would like to remove duplicates rows based on field 1 and 2, but separately for each colour. Desired output:

```
1    345    a   blue
3    452    c   blue
3    342    d   green
1    345    f   green
```

I can achieve this output using a `for loop` that iterates over the colours:

```
for i in $(awk '{ print $4 }' file.txt | sort -u); do
   grep -w ${i} |
   awk '!x[$1,$2]++' >> output.txt
done
```

But this is slow. Is there any way to get this output without use of a loop?

Thank you.

Comment: Just realized this may be simpler using `sort`. Something like: `sort -u -k1,3 -k2,3` Let me know what you guys think.

Comment: I'm missing the logic. Why are you keeping `1    345    blue` but dropping `3    342    green` in the expected output?

Comment: @jlliagre, sorry about that. It's fixed.

Comment: Still unclear, your example is simply removing duplicate lines. Fields 1 and 2 have no particular impact here. You should better explain the expected logic.

Comment: `perl -ane 'print if !$seen{$F[0], $F[1], $F[3]}++' file.txt` - conversion to awk is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I added an additional field. My actual file contains many columns, I was just trying to simplify it for this post, but clearly I over-simplified. Now each line is unique, but I need to remove duplicates in column 1 and 2 for each unique colour. I hope this better explains it.

Comment: @Rish That's the same as removing duplicates in column 1, 2, and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for the example, it is simple as:

```
$ awk 'arr[$1,$2,$4]++{next} 1' file
1    345   a    blue
3    452   c    blue
3    342   d    green
1    345   f    green
```

Or, you can negate that:

```
$ awk '!arr[$1,$2,$4]++' file
```

You can also use GNU sort for the same which may be faster:

```
$ sort -k4,4 -k2,2 -k1,1 -u file
```

Comment: My goodness, I over-thought this question far too much. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try this too:

```
awk '!a[$1,$2,$4]++'   Input_file
```

Comment: This is the right answer but by convention when you have an array that's being used to test if an index has been seen before we name the array `seen[]`, not `A[]`. Never use all upper case for variable names, btw, for the usual reasons (avoid clashes with builtin variable names like NR, FNR, etc. and avoid it looking like you're using a builtin variable name when you aren't).

Comment: Thank you Akshay for encouragement. Thank you Ed Morton for your suggestion, point taken.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13! This was the syntax I used in the original loop in my question. I  just failed to extend it incorporate an additional field for some reason... Thanks again.